# How to align comments with lstlistings?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I am using `listings` with these settings:

```
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false
}
```

I like the proportionally set font, but I want to be able to align comments of different lines. Is it possible to do some kind of tabbing with the `lstlisting` environment?

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;  // A float
  int anAptlyNamedInteger;  // An integer
\end{lstlisting}
```

I would like the two comments to be aligned horizontally.

Comment: That might be quite difficult to achieve with `columns=fullflexible`, which tells `listings` not to even try to achieve any sort of column alignment. Perhaps it can be done by using the comment sequence `//` as an "escape", which exits the pseudocode syntax hilighting and admits TeX commands to be used.

Comment: Good idea, I think that is more or less what Peter just did below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are willing to change the code, then you could define an `escapechar=\&`, which allows you to enter a `&` to escape back to LaTeX ande execute a macro. Then wrap the comments in something such as:

```
\newcommand*{\Comment}[1]{\hfill\makebox[3.0cm][l]{#1}}%
```

to get the alignment you desire:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\Comment}[1]{\hfill\makebox[3.0cm][l]{#1}}%
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  escapechar=\&% char to escape out of listings and back to LaTeX
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  float f;  &\Comment{// A float}&
  int anAptlyNamedInteger;  &\Comment{// An integer}&
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

This uses code from [I want to indent the next line by an exactly specified position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764) to save the position of a comment (using `\SP`) and re-use the position later (using `\UP`). It uses the `savepos` module from [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
% Taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69076/5764
% \zsaveposx is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{\let\zsaveposx\zsavepos}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{hposcnt}
\renewcommand*{\thehposcnt}{hpos\number\value{hposcnt}}
\newcommand*{\SP}{% set position
  \stepcounter{hposcnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt s}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\UP}{% use previous position
  \zsaveposx{\thehposcnt u}%
  \zref@refused{\thehposcnt s}%
  \zref@refused{\thehposcnt u}%
  \kern\zposx{\thehposcnt s}sp\relax
  \kern-\zposx{\thehposcnt u}sp\relax
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  numbers=none,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  mathescape
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  float f; $\hspace{250pt}\SP$// A float
  int anAptlyNamedInteger;  $\UP$// An integer
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

In the example above (note that [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `mathescape` option has been made active) the first comment is set at a specific position, and that position is saved using `\SP`. Subsequent horizontal alignment is achieved using `\UP`.

The solution requires at least two compiles, since it uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like system/reading from the `.aux` file.