# How can I add annotations at the end of each line of a listing?

Tags: listings, comments

(I'm new to LaTeX.)

I'd like to annotate each line of a (Java) listing (typeset with `listings`) to specify the computation time associated with it.

However, I can't simply edit the file and add the annotations in the code itself, because those annotations contain special characters that get my IDE really upset.

Therefore, I have to add those annotations in LaTeX, somehow. Hence my question: how can I add a comment at the end of a line in a listing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. What you're asking for can be done if you use an `lstlisting` algorithm. However, that might be dfficult/impossible if you're inserting code that resides in an external file (using `\lstinputlisting`).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31349/how-to-align-comments-with-lstlistings