# Color a single listings comment delimiter (shell transcript language style)?

Tags: color, listings

I've wanted to have a sort of a shell transcript language style in with listings, where the shell prompt and actual commands are emphasized, and the rest of the text is a bit "muted".

Best I could get to for now, is define the basic style as "muted"/"faded"/"greyed out", and then treating my shell prompt character (here `$`) as a single comment delimiter, and then have the remaining comment be styled in full black color and bolded:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{ShellTranscript}
{sensitive=false,
morecomment=[l][\color{black}\bfseries]{ \$ },
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black!70},
}

\begin{document}

Here we go:

\begin{lstlisting}[language=ShellTranscript]

user@box:~ $ ls /usr/
bin  games  include  lib  local  man  sbin  share  src
user@box:~ $ ls /var/
backups  cache  lib  local  lock  log  mail  opt  run  spool  swap  tmp
user@box:~ $ echo 'be careful of $ in there!'
be careful of $ in there!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image: output]

However, what I'd really want is this:

[image: desired-output]

That is: just the comment delimiter (i.e. just the prompt character `$`) should be red and non-bold; text afterwards (actual command) should be black and bold; remaining text like output should be muted/gray - and `$` in "output text" should NOT be styled (which probably means that in order to declare "comment", one has to take check if the line starts with `user@box` and contains a `$`, then if it does, take that `$` as a comment delimiter).

Can that be achieved with listings - and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adapt @matexmatics' solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706145/36296 like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\colorlet{dollarcol}{red}

\lstdefinelanguage{ShellTranscript}
{sensitive=false,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black!30},
moredelim=[s][\colorlet{dollarcol}{red}]{user@box:~},
moredelim=**[il][\textcolor{dollarcol}{\$}\color{black}\bfseries\colorlet{dollarcol}{black}]{\$}
}

\begin{document}

Here we go:

\begin{lstlisting}[language=ShellTranscript]

user@box:~ $ ls /usr/
bin  games  include  lib  local  man  sbin  share  src
user@box:~ $ ls /var/
backups  cache  lib  local  lock  log  mail  opt  run  spool  swap  tmp
user@box:~ $ echo 'be careful of $ in there!'
be careful of $ in there!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]